# What is the best generator for scala to call a graphql interface

Tags: scala, graphql, code-generation, openapi-generator

I have to test an application via graphql. As I used openapi generator in the past to produce java code for a rest api, I would like to ask if anybody did the same for scala to access graphql interface. Is it possible with openapi-generator? Or is there a better generator?

Comment: Your question is too broad and any answer will be opnion-based. Here you have an article about [What topics can be asked about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help.

Answer (score 0):

The official [graphql page](https://graphql.org/) has a section that list tools for different languges. In the part that [list grpahql tools for scala](https://graphql.org/code/#scala) you can find:

- [sangria](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria): only lets you generate the server from scala code
- [caliban](https://ghostdogpr.github.io/caliban/): lets you generate the server from scala code, but also the client from the schema definition.

Not sure if there are more tools for scala that are not being showed in that list. I can't say that `caliban` is the best, because there is no other one than that